# Where can I get the C code for the bash login?

Tags: macos, login

I suspect there is something awry with my /usr/bin/login (Mac OS X) because terminal hangs when I open it. After moving the login binary, terminal works except if I have to sudo--then same as before.
I do not know where my original install CD is, and if I could manage to find it, recompiling the login binary would be much easier anyway. It is NOT in coreutils, so where is it?

Comment: I doubt strongly that the cause is what you think it is.

Comment: This really doesn't seem like a StackOverflow question either... maybe more so SuperUser?

Comment: How are you calling `login(1)`? Are you running it with euid == root? (Or are you expecting to start a new session as your current user account?)

Comment: I am the same admin-type user I have always been. I am the only user of the computer. This has happened once before (over a year ago) and the problem was fixed with a new login function. I forget where I got the code.

Comment: The problem started with trying to add a daemon with launchtcl command. The file appearently did not exist, and the next time I opened the terminal, the problem started.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the Apple part of Stack Exchange?

Comment: I am sorry, I was not aware of apple stack exchange. If I can find out how to move the question, I will.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does the same thing happen in [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/)?

Comment: Btw, if it makes any difference: [Here is the binary](http://cl.ly/2H2F1G12140a3W0u182v) from my own computer (Lion)

Comment: I tried the binary, and I get dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
      I really think I need the source code so I can compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you can download the source:
http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/usr.bin/login/